# LTspice Sample Hold

Tags: ltspice

I'm using the sample/hold blok in LTspice. 
As shown in the attached pictures and LTspice simulation, the output has not the same amplitude of the input.

For example the input amplitude is 60kV while the output is 70V.

[image]

Can you help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Also see [this](http://ltspicegoodies.ltwiki.org/Pwr.html#limsh), for a bit more insight.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Undocumented LTspice](http://www.ltwiki.org/index.php?title=Undocumented_LTspice#SampleHold_.28aka_Sample.29) the output voltage saturation levels default to -10V to 10V.

To solve the issue, you should change the output voltage saturation level as follows (by adding SpiceLine as shown):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is in continuation to what @Huisman answered, and my comment. It seems that the [ltwiki page for S&H](http://ltwiki.org/?title=Undocumented_LTspice#SampleHold_.28aka_Sample.29) doesn't have this information (yet, though it's known, but the person taking care of it is only human): the `SAMPLEHOLD` has a builtin clamping resistor which defaults to `Rclamp=1`. Since the default output resistor is `Rout=1k`, this means that, when the `Vhigh` and `Vlow` limits are reached, the output signal is attenuated by `Rclamp||Rout=999.001m`. The effect is still as the one given in the [link](http://ltspicegoodies.ltwiki.org/Pwr.html#limsh) in my comment, but now you know precisely why.

What @Huisman said about changing the limits is true, and sometimes you'll see `Vhigh=1e308`, even in the default library (though in the `OTA`, mostly), but that may cause numerical issues if you are, indeed, working with very high values, so the alternative way to deal with the limiting is to ignore `Vhigh` and `Vlow` in favour of setting `Rclamp=1meg` and `Rout=1`, which would not abuse the dynamic range too much, while also providing accurate output within 6 decimals. `Rclamp=0` will default to `1`. If `double` precision is needed, then `Vhigh` and `Vlow` is the way to go, provided extreme dynamic ranges are not reached; `1meg...1g` should be a sensible limit.

Also, unused inputs for the A-devices (`SAMPLEHOLD` being one of them) are internally connected to the 8th pin, which is the ground pin. Therefore, if the ground pin is connected to node `0`, the unused pins need not be connected to ground (as you did with the inverting input).